# Use and test hCaptcha on localhost

Tags: captcha, hcaptcha

How can I test hCaptcha on localhost?

When using the key, I get a CORS error, and for choosing sites for the key, it specifically states `... localhost will not work`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are test keys you should use for testing, see https://docs.hcaptcha.com/#integration-testing-test-keys

Referenced Below:

> Test Key Set: Publisher Account
>
> Test parameter Value
>
> Site Key   `10000000-ffff-ffff-ffff-000000000001`
> Secret Key `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000`
>
> Test Key Set: Enterprise Account (Safe End User)
>
> Test parameter Value
>
> Site Key   `20000000-ffff-ffff-ffff-000000000002`
> Secret Key `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000`
>
> Test Key Set: Enterprise Account (Bot Detected)
>
> Test parameter Value
>
> Site Key   `30000000-ffff-ffff-ffff-000000000003`
> Secret Key `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

PS: I confirmed this with the hCaptcha team.

PSS: A different work around would be use change your `hosts` file to point `your-website.com` to localhost to do testing.

Comment: i'm running into the same problem... how am i supposed to embed the hcaptcha into my site, if i can never see if it actually works, if challenges are shown properly etc? how will "keys that always generate a passcode without asking a question" help me with that?

Comment: @devman a work around is to just change your `hosts` file to point `your-website.com` to localhost.

Answer (score 7):

in the browser replace localhost to 127.0.0.1

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDsPW.png